# Isoelectric pH of colloids?

Tags: biochemistry, equilibrium, ions, aqueous-solution, ph

How did we derive the relation between the [isoelectric pH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoelectric_point) and the dissociation constants for the amino and carboxyl groups on zwitterionic amino acids.

$$pI=\frac {pK_{a1}+pK_{a2}}{2}$$
where $$\ce{NH3^+-R2(COO^{-})<=>NH3^+-R2(COOH)-K_{a1}}$$
$$\ce{NH3^+-R2(COO^{-})<=>NH2-R2(COO^{-})-K_{a2}}$$

For more complicated cases (charged side groups) and their isoelectric pH, [here is one site](http://www.mhhe.com/physsci/chemistry/carey5e/Ch27/ch27-1-4.html) which just posts the equations without any derivation. Besides this, there is no reference I could find for this derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the equilibria in dilute aqueous solution:

$$\ce{H2A+ \rightleftharpoons HA + H+} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ K_{a_1}=\frac{[HA][H^+]}{[H_2A^+]}$$

$$\ce{HA \rightleftharpoons A^- + H+} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ K_{a_2}=\frac{[A^-][H^+]}{[HA]}$$

At the isoelectric point:

$$[H_2A^+]=[A^-]$$

Using the expressions for $K_{a_1}$ and $K_{a_2}$, we find:

$$\frac{{[HA]}[H^+]}{K_{a_1}}=\frac{K_{a_2}[HA]}{[H^+]}$$

$$[H^+]^2 = K_{a_1}K_{a_2}$$

$$pH_{isoelectric}=\frac{pK_{a_1}+pK_{a_2}}{2}$$

See also [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_dissociation_constant#Isoelectric_point) on Wikipedia.